# Create Parent with existing children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

Does anyone know how to create a new parent with existing children?

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :jobs
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :jobs
end

class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :quote
  belongs_to :order
end
```

With nested variables, I can build one or more jobs (children) with a new order (parent) and the create method then automatically creates the new parent with it's new children.  What I have though, is a group of existing children (jobs that were created in a quote), and I want to include them in a new parent form.  When hitting submit to create the new order, I want it to create the new parent, and update the selected children with that new parent ID.

I have messy code that will do this in the create method by saving a new order (parent), then updating each of the jobs (children) with the new order_id, but is there any way to do this automatically?

---

The actual code is complex, so here's the crux of it.

Let's assume there is a quote with several jobs, therefore the quote_id variable in all these jobs point back to the quote and @quote.jobs = array of these jobs.

Here's what I have now:

In the Order model I added:

```
attr_accessor :quote_id
```

In the Order controller:

```
def new quote_id
  @quote = Quote.find(quote_id)
  @order = Order.new
```

and in the view

```
<%= simple_form_for @order, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :quote_id, value: @quote.id, as: :hidden %>
  <%= f.input :account_number %>
  ...
  <table>
    <thead><tr> ... column headings here ... </tr></thead>
    <tbody>
      <% @quote.jobs.each do |q| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= q.description %></td>
          <td><%= q.price %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
      <tr><%= ... add a row with the total price ... %></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <%= f.button :submit, "Place My Order" %>
<% end $>
```

Then in the Order controller

```
def create
  ...
  if @order.save
    Quote.find(params[quote_id]).jobs.each do |job|
      job.update(order_id: @order.id)
    end
  end
  ...
```

What I would prefer is for the job parameters to be handled as nested objects in the form so they can be automatically updated on an Order create with the order.id and perhaps a couple of other parameters.  I've tried (in the controller)

```
@order = Order.new
@quote.jobs.each do |job|
  @order.jobs << job
end
```

but they're not showing up in a form with the usual nested format and if that worked, I don't know if they would actually be updated.

Comment: In either your UI or your relevant code, how do you load the existing job objects that will be associated with this new order object/how are you submitting the data to your app (via a post/create call from a form in your web ui, etc.)? For me, not knowing how your code receives the data to associate makes it more difficult to offer a potential solution.

Comment: can you post your view code to see what you're actually doing in there?

Answer (score 0):

Since an Order accepts nested attributes for a Job, I suppose you could just manually create and populate the nested jobs fields - as hidden fields - when you build your order form.

```
<% @quote.jobs.each_with_index do |job, index| %>
  <input type='hidden' name='order[jobs_attributes][<% index %>][FIELDNAME]' id='order_jobs_attributes_<% index %>_FIELDNAME' value='<% job.something %>' />
<% end %>
```

I'm sure there's a cleaner way with simple_form/form helpers to use `= f.input` to build the hidden fields but I was admittedly being lazy above!

Comment: Actually, I was mistaken. Using the last section in my post above, @order.jobs << job, is recognized in the forms and the usual nested form does produce just what you're suggesting.  The problem is that the create method doesn't handle it and gives me:  
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in OrdersController#create
Couldn't find TranslationJob with ID=392 for Order with ID=